# Time Series forecast - Unable to convert forecast into actual values

Tags: r, time-series

This is a time series for inflow of tickets for a group, trying to estimate 
the inflow for next 3 months.

New to time series forecast , trying to do it step by step by referring few examples.

```
inflow<-c(487,424,353,2116,1740,3767,4267,5278,4042,7224)

plot(inflow)

# Monthly time series

inflow_ts<-ts(inflow,start=c(2017,10),end=c(2018,7),frequency=12)

print(inflow_ts,calendar = T)

# Plotting the time series

plot.ts(inflow_ts)


#Forecast

#Step1 : Model Identification

#Stationarity Test - Disckey Fuller Test

# Null hypothesis is that Time Series is not stationary

adf.test(inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")

# Opscomputeinflow_ts is not stationary since p value is > 0.5

#Dickey-Fuller = -1.6092, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.7213

# Differenciate the time series - Level1

diff1_inflow_ts<- diff(inflow_ts)

plot(diff1_inflow_ts)

adf.test(diff1_inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")

# diff1_Opscomputeinflow_ts is not stationary since p value is > 0.5
# Dickey-Fuller = -1.1885, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.8815

# Differenciate the time series - Level2

diff2_inflow_ts<- diff(diff1_inflow_ts)

plot(diff2_inflow_ts)

adf.test(diff2_inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")

# diff2_Opscomputeinflow_ts is not stationary since p value is > 0.5
# Dickey-Fuller = -1.4501, Lag order = 1, p-value = 0.7819


# Differenciate the time series - Level3

diff3_inflow_ts<- diff(diff2_inflow_ts)

plot(diff3_inflow_ts)

adf.test(diff3_inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")

# diff3_Opscomputeinflow_ts is not stationary since p value is > 0.5
# Dickey-Fuller = -0.84809, Lag order = 1, p-value = 0.9429

# Differenciate the time series - Level4

diff4_inflow_ts<- diff(diff3_inflow_ts)

plot(diff4_inflow_ts)

adf.test(diff4_inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")


#Try log to make it stationary

# Take log of the time series 

log_inflow_ts<- log(inflow_ts)

plot(log_inflow_ts)

adf.test(log_inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")

# log_Opscomputeinflow_ts is not stationary since p value is > 0.5
# Dickey-Fuller = -1.1857, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.8826



# Take log and diff of the time series 

diff_log_inflow_ts<- diff(log(inflow_ts))

plot(diff_log_inflow_ts)

adf.test(diff_log_inflow_ts,alternative = "stationary")

# diff_log_Opscomputeinflow_ts is  stationary since p value is < 0.5
# Dickey-Fuller = -5.9701, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.01



# check ACF and PACF plots

acf(diff_log_inflow_ts)

pacf(diff_log_inflow_ts)


# No significance levels of AR or MA


arima(diff_log_inflow_ts,c(0,0,0))

# Step -4 Diagnosis


arima.final<-arima(diff_log_inflow_ts,c(0,0,0))

tsdiag(arima.final)

#forecast using final model


predicted<-predict(arima.final,n.ahead = 3)

predicted
```

output:

```
$pred
           Aug       Sep       Oct
2018 0.2996556 0.2996556 0.2996556

$se
           Aug       Sep       Oct
2018 0.6285461 0.6285461 0.6285461
```

I tried to convert this to actual values. but unable to get the exact values

used exp and diffinv to get the actual values.

```
> diffinv(exp(0.2996556))
[1] 0.000000 1.349394
```

Comment: Is your question how to obtain the values from`predicted` in form of a, say, `data.frame`? (Sorry if I missed that, but I didn't read all the lines.)

Comment: Prediction output shown is in the form of diff(log(inflow_ts)), where "inflow_ts" contains monthly volume inflow. Now i need actual ticket predicted volume.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571327/time-series-forecasting-inverse-differencing-r this helps?

Comment: diffinv(diff(exp((0.2996556)), xi=487)) is also not working.